# Attempting to protect a question that is no longer eligible for protection silently fails

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, protected-questions, javascript

I opened a question that had just gotten a new answer. The answer scores were as follows:

- 65
- 10
- 7
- 4
- -1 (new answer)
- 0 (deleted)
- 0 (deleted)
- -2 (deleted)

The protect link was present on the question. I checked out the new answer, thought it looked ok, and upvoted it to a 0 score.

When I then clicked the link to protect the question it popped up the dialog, but clicking the Protect button did nothing. I reloaded the page and the protect link was gone. Apparently my upvote of the answer had made the question unable to be protected.

Either the link should be removed when a vote changes the question's eligibility for protection, or a proper error message should be displayed to the user.

For example,

> An error occurred while protecting the question. The question may not be eligible for protection. Reload the page and try again.

Comment: The protect/unprotect routes currently have no concept of sending back error messages. If any condition fails, you just get a 404 error. Sending proper error messages for why it failed would be quite some effort.

Comment: @animuson At least if the request returns a response >= 400 it should say an error occurred even if it can't know what the error was

Comment: I think "An error occurred while protecting the question" is enough, and would be the same as other error messages, e.g. when posting comment fails.

Comment: Apparently, this was because of [this restriction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions): "*[...] provided the question has received at least **one answer from a user with less than 10 reputation.***" (emphasize mine)